# Variable NSString anos working with NSLocalizedString Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

I am developing an app in Xcode using Objective-c and I have a problem with an NSStrign variable and NSLocalizedString (to translate to other idioms).

My problem is that if I use this way, it works great:
(All this code is in my ViewDidLoad method)

```
NSString *decDate = @"11/2016";
_updateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updated: %@", decDate];
```

And the result is:

> Updated: 11/2016

But if I try to use NSLocalizedString to translate this String, it doesn't´t works:

```
 NSString *decDate = @"11/2016";
_updateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString (@"Updated: %@", decDate)];
```

In this case, Xcode said me "Unused variable 'decDate'"

And the result is:

> Updated: NSString

Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Check this out : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocalizedstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString` takes two arguments, the key and a comment. You're using `decDate` as the comment.

Your `stringWithFormat` should look like this:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Updated: %@", nil), decDate]
```